# base64_encode and decode escape char problem

Tags: php

Hi I've made a paste bin site to share code with a school work group, the problem that I have is when I save code in the db I use `base64_encode(code)`, when I try to show with
`base64_decode(code)` it shows with escaped chars like:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf \"thi is a test\"\\n

exit 0
```

How can I show it, with out escaped chars?

Thanks, Manolo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your web hosting provider has the "[magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php)" mis-feature enabled.  Magic quotes is the [product of a bygone era](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.why.php) of PHP and [should no longer be used](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php).

You should probably [disable them](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).  In particular, you're suffering from `magic_quotes_runtime`, which can be disabled on a script-by-script basis rather than needing an .htaccess or php.ini change.

Comment: Hi Charles i try to add php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off in .htaccess an the host troguth error 500, i cant use php.ini, how can i fix it in other form?

Comment: @manolo, to fix the problem with extra backslashes in the database, you can change `magic_quotes_runtime` by calling [`set_magic_quotes_runtime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-magic-quotes-runtime.php).  If you find yourself contaminated with the GPC magic quotes, then you'll need to programatically strip them.  There is example code on the "disable them" page I linked above.

Comment: Ready! I request to my sysadmin that remove magic_quotes modules and all work ok! Thanks for all!